# bootstrap css messes with d3 (because... huh?)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I'm working on a charting library for my workplace. I'm using d3.

For some reason, adding the bootstrap css screws the whole thing over, and I'm getting these cryptic error messages:

```
Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute height="-74.39999999999999"
Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute height="-24.799999999999997" 
Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute height="-124" 
Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute height="-57.866666666666674"
```

Here's a [before](http://jsfiddle.net/gjB8r/) and [after](http://jsfiddle.net/gjB8r/1/) jsfiddle for you to test yourself. I have no idea what might cause this, **how does a css file manage to create a js error** like that is beyond me. googling resulted in nothing. I'm completely baffled. Any bright ideas?

**update**

I just realized that this only happens if the div doesn't have a defined height. I have written the code so that if the div doesn't have a height the svg should define it as 320px (just a random figure that makes sense to me), but it seems I also need the containing div to be of the same size or else bootstrap gets mad.

I've added `min-width: 320px;` and it [does solve](http://jsfiddle.net/gjB8r/2/) the problem but I'm still completely wondering if anyone has any idea what the hell is going on (and if there's a better solution than giving everything a defined width. I'd like to avoid that for now)

Comment: Could you tell us what the difference is between your two fiddles?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff the second one has bootstrap.min.css as an external resource. That's it. That's my question - why adding it causes an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) reset that Bootstrap includes seems to be causing your problem.

Evidence: http://jsfiddle.net/Wf8Vz/1/

The relevant Bootstrap CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

For why Bootstrap does this, see http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

The Bootstrap docs cover some recommended workarounds for scenarios like yours: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties
(Basically, add a counter-reset back to the browser default, `box-sizing: content-box;`, that only affects the section of the DOM where you're having trouble.)